# source not found - Application has stopped working unexpectedly

Tags: android

when i click submit button... It displays as "source not found" when i debug... and in the  device it shows as application has stopped working unexpectedly...

```
Button btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);
        btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {                           
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //finish();
                //Intent DiscIntent = new Intent (view.getContext(), Disclaimer.class);
                //startActivityForResult(DiscIntent, 0);
                if(ValidateInformation())
                {
                    EditText etUserName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtUserName);

                if(UserNameAvailability(view, etUserName.getText().toString().trim()))
```

My Logcat details are below...

```
   01-12 16:52:39.664: E/AndroidRuntime(338): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
01-12 16:52:39.674: E/AndroidRuntime(338): java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
01-12 16:52:39.674: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at android.util.Log.println(Native Method)
01-12 16:52:39.674: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at android.util.Log.w(Log.java:157)
01-12 16:52:39.674: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at com.anb.eCalculator.RegisterActivity.UserNameAvailability(RegisterActivity.java:236)
01-12 16:52:39.674: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at com.anb.eCalculator.RegisterActivity$3.onClick(RegisterActivity.java:73)
01-12 16:52:39.674: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
01-12 16:52:39.674: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4179)
01-12 16:52:39.674: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:6541)
01-12 16:52:39.674: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3709)
01-12 16:52:39.674: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
01-12 16:52:39.674: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
01-12 16:52:39.674: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
01-12 16:52:39.674: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
01-12 16:52:39.674: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
01-12 16:52:39.674: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
01-12 16:52:39.674: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
01-12 16:52:39.674: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1659)
01-12 16:52:39.674: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
01-12 16:52:39.674: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2061)
01-12 16:52:39.674: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
01-12 16:52:39.674: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1691)
01-12 16:52:39.674: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-12 16:52:39.674: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-12 16:52:39.674: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
01-12 16:52:39.674: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-12 16:52:39.674: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-12 16:52:39.674: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
01-12 16:52:39.674: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
01-12 16:52:39.674: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My UserNameAvailability function is below

```
protected boolean UserNameAvailability(View view, final String sUserName)
```

{
    boolean result = false;

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(getResources().getString(R.string.targetnamespace), getResources().getString(R.string.usernameavailabilitymethod));
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.dotNet = true;

PropertyInfo piUserName = new PropertyInfo();
piUserName.name = "UserName";

request.addProperty(piUserName, sUserName);

HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(getResources().getString(R.string.webserviceurl));                 
    try {
        httpTransport.debug =true;
        httpTransport.call(getResources().getString(R.string.usernameavailabilitysoapaction), envelope);                    
        SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse(); 
        if (!response.toString().equals("false")) {
            result = true;

        }
        else
        {
            alertBox("User Name already exists.Please enter different username.");
        }

      }catch (Exception exception) {
        Log.w("UserRegistration - RegisterActivity", exception.getMessage());
      }


      return result;
```

}

My complete button click event is below

```
 Button btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);
        btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {                           
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //finish();
                //Intent DiscIntent = new Intent (view.getContext(), Disclaimer.class);
                //startActivityForResult(DiscIntent, 0);
                if(ValidateInformation())
                {
                    EditText etUserName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtUserName);

                if(UserNameAvailability(view, etUserName.getText().toString().trim()))
                {
                 EditText etFirstName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtFirstName);
                 EditText etLastName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtLastName);        
                 EditText etEmail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);      
                 EditText etQuery= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtQuery);
                 EditText etTelephone = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtTelePhone);
                 EditText etOrganization = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtOrganization);
                 EditText etRegion = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtRegionCountry);
                 EditText etPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtPassword);
                 EditText etConfirmPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtConfirmPassword);//Added By Prakash
                 //EditText etUserName1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtUserName); 



                Bundle bunUserInfo = new Bundle();
                bunUserInfo.putString("UserName", etUserName.getText().toString());
                bunUserInfo.putString("FirstName", etFirstName.getText().toString());
                bunUserInfo.putString("LastName", etLastName.getText().toString());
                bunUserInfo.putString("Email", etEmail.getText().toString());
                bunUserInfo.putString("Query", etQuery.getText().toString());
                bunUserInfo.putString("Telephone", etTelephone.getText().toString());
                bunUserInfo.putString("Organization", etOrganization.getText().toString());
                bunUserInfo.putString("Region", etRegion.getText().toString());
                bunUserInfo.putString("Password", etPassword.getText().toString());
                bunUserInfo.putString("ConfirmPassword", etConfirmPassword.getText().toString());
                //bunUserInfo.putString("UserName", etUserName1.getText().toString());




                Intent goToNextActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Disclaimer.class);
                goToNextActivity.putExtras(bunUserInfo);
                startActivity(goToNextActivity);
                }
                else
                {
                    alertBox("User Name already exists. Please enter different User Name.");
                }
            }

            }
        });
```

Comment: Are you sure that your entire code is just that much?

Comment: You might want to post the source of your function `UserNameAvailability` as well as the exception happens there :)

Comment: Your log says that at line 236 of your RegisterActivity class you are trying to log a warning message without any message text.

Comment: I have posted my UserNameAvailability function... plz check

Comment: I have also posted my complete button click even

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that UserNameAvailability calls Log.w with a null argument somewhere.

Look for a call to Log.w in UserNameAvailability where either the tag or the message is null.

Comment: I am unable to figure out clearly... I posted my whole code... can u plz look into it and say me clearly... sorry... i am new to android development

Comment: i feel exception.getMessage() seems null, instead of that use some constant string or exeption.printStacktrace().

Answer (score 1):

Change this line

```
Log.w("UserRegistration - RegisterActivity", exception.getMessage());
```

to

```
Log.w("UserRegistration - RegisterActivity", "Error message is "+exception.getMessage(), exception);
```

This way you will always have a message (and a stacktrace in your log), even if the `exception.getMessage()` function returns null;